# Implementation of pdfmake in Angularjs2/Ionic2

Tags: java, ionic-framework, ionic2, pdfmake

I am creating an application in ionic 2 framework(based on angularjs2). Here i am providing data in forums and this data is shown by the pdf. 
can anyone please tell  how to install pdfmake in angularjs2 or ionic 2 and some basic snippets to use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to find a solution to this myself. I came across a Plunker here that might help you: https://plnkr.co/edit/7tPFTAjKWwaRp1IbT0Tg?p=preview

You need to install pdfmake in your project with Bower (via bower install pdfmake)

then reference the files in your index.html

```
  <script src='pdfmake.min.js'></script>
  <script src='vfs_fonts.js'></script>
```

(It might help you to move the two js files into the same file as Index.html)

then you need a js file to actually build the pdf (which in the example plunker looks like this:)

```
function buildPdf(value) {
    var pdfContent = value;

    var docDefinition = {
        content: [{
            text: 'My name is: '
        }]
    }
    console.log(pdfContent);
    return docDefinition;
}
```

And you use that in your component like this (where 'export class App' is the name of your component):

```
export class App {
  public item: {firstName: string, lastName: string} = {firstName: 'Peter', lastName: 'Parker'};
    pdf: any;
    buildPdf: any = new buildPdf();

    openPdf() {
        this.pdf = pdfMake;
        this.buildPdf = buildPdf;
        this.pdf.createPdf(buildPdf(this.item)).open();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!